# USB boot Lenovo Ideapad S340

Tags: boot, usb, lenovo

I have spent days trying to get an Lenovo ideapad S340 boot from a USB.

Would someone care to walk me through step by step?

I have searched on the internet, changed BIOS settings, created USBs (universal usb installer, unetbootin ) and am going round in circles.

I do have technical background and can follow instructions, but need some guidance to avoid the pitfalls.

I am stuck with getting this USB to work.

Comment: 1) Create and verify your USB: http://tutorials.ubuntu.com. 2) Boot from the USB. If you follow the instructions, and if your hardware permits booting from USB, then it's really that simple. We can offer more specific help if you have a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks user535733 and karel.
It worked eventually :) by using Rufus to build the USB.
The steps were picked up from the tutorial: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview

another page that really helped is here:
https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-U-and-S-Series-Notebooks/S340-15IWL-Can-t-Legacy-Boot-from-USB/m-p/4477110
 its about changing settings in the ROM during startup.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution :-)